# Slot type AMAZON.NUMBER won't handle larger number

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

My intent schema uses an [AMAZON.NUMBER](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#number) slot:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "MyIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "Foo",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Smaller numbers like "two thousand" show up properly in the [IntentRequest](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/custom-standard-request-types-reference#intentrequest)...

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "request": {
    "Intent": {
      "name": "MyIntent",
      "slots": {
        "Foo": {
          "name": "Foo",
          "value": "2000"
        }
      }
    },
    "type": "IntentRequest"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to handle expressions such as "four point five million":

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "request": {
    "Intent": {
      "name": "MyIntent",
      "slots": {
        "Foo": {
          "name": "Foo",
          "value": "?"
        }
      }
    },
    "type": "IntentRequest"
  }
}
```

Do I need to use an [AMAZON.LITERAL](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#literal) slot and feed the value into my own number expression parser? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMAZON.NUMBER slot type will not handle well sequences of numbers (e.g. a telephone or bank account number) and in my experience it will not handle decimals or numbers that have any "utterance" between them. On top of that,  AMAZON.LITERAL is deprecated so it may be difficult to capture this kind of numbers using the current API. Sorry.

Comment: Bummer. I guess the only hope is that Amazon makes improvements to AMAZON.NUMBER in the future. Thanks!